# Testing AWS spot instance provisioning

Tags: unit-testing, amazon-web-services, testing, amazon-ec2

My company is looking to switch to using Spot pricing when provisioning EC2 instances. I've been tasked with writing some unit tests that test things such as:

- Our Spot instance count in at a certain threshold
- When that threshold isn't met on demand replacements are brought up to replace 
  them

I'm not an adept tester and haven't had much exposure to AWS on the whole. So my question is what approach, tools, software could I use to begin implementing this? My initial thinking is to write a bash script with AWS CLI commands and go from there.

Any pointers or recommendations would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I thought about this a little and I would recommend you have two auto scaling groups, one for [spot instances](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/latest/userguide/US-SpotInstances.html) and one for on-demand instances. For the spot instances auto scaling group you would essentially set your desired capacity. For the on demand auto scaling group you would simply set the min and max to 0.

Next you would setup two cloud watch alarms. One would be for `GroupInServiceInstances` less than whatever maximum you declared. This would be set to on by default. Another would be `GroupInServiceInstances` equal to the maximum you declared. This would be set to off by default.

Now when the `GroupInServiceInstances`alarm for instances less than your desired maximum goes off it would invoke a lambda function. This lambda function would do the following:

- Enable the `GroupInServiceInstances` equal to your maximum capacity alarm
- Disable the `GroupInServiceInstances` less than your desired capacity alarm
- Call the auto scaling group API to get ( max instances - currently running instances )
- Set the min and max instances in the on demand auto scaling group to whatever that value is

It also would be a good idea to setup a simple notification service topic that emails someone when the spot instance auto scaling group has an insufficient number of instances after X amount of time. That lets you decide if you need to rework the spot prices.

Now when the `GroupInServiceInstances` equal to your maximum desired capacity alarm goes off, it will invoke a lambda function to do the following:

- Enable the `GroupInServiceInstances` less than desired alarm
- Disable the `GroupInServiceInstances` equal to desired alarm
- Set the min and max on demand auto scaling group instances desired to 0
- This will essentially terminate all the instances in the on demand auto scaling group so you can revert back to using the (hopefully) lower cost spot instances

This solution does require knowledge of Lambda, but I think it ends up a lot more automated and reduces the additional logic a CLI script would require.